# What is the statement to use for executing a command allied with a different software in python?

Tags: python

I am using Unix OS and I want to know how to execute a command that is executable from a different software in Python script.
     I have this software installed into my system called HAL Tools and it has a command called maf2hal with two arguments which are input and output files. The path for the command is saved in my .bash_profile under PATH variable. I call the command from UNIX likewise:

```
[root ~]$ maf2hal inputfile outputfile
```

I want to call this command from a Python script. What is the statement or function that I need to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Use [os.popen()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to execute command:

```
import os
os.popen("maf2hal inputfile outputfile")
```

2.[subprocess.call()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

```
from subprocess import call
call("maf2hal inputfile outputfile", shell=True)
```

Comment: Don't suggest to use `os.popen()`. `Your 2nd option, `subprocess`, is *the* way to go nowadays.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for the feedback, I also found there was a good summary on previous post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: @varshith-chakrapani also check this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: Yeah I checked the previous discussion. Seems that subprocess indeed is better suited. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

A sample command can be

```
import os
os.system('maf2hal inputfile outputfile')
```

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted...

Comment: @That1Guy Perhaps, the other answer is better ..... But still :( ..Thanks for +1

Comment: "The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function." This answer is not wrong, but inferior to other ways of doing it.

Comment: @glglgl. yeah this is an inferior alternative. (Thats why the downvote I guess), but thanks for re-affirming that this answer is not wrong ...:)...